# i can't update anymore with the App store

Tags: appcenter

E: The repository 'cdrom://elementary OS 5.1 *hera* - stable amd64 (20200204) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent this error you have to comment the line in your sources.list which asks for a CD Rom. An option to achieve this is by using command line.

## 1. Create a backup of the file first

Open your terminal application and paste or type the line

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

The system will ask for your administrator password, you have to type it. If there is no error message, continue with the next step:

## 2. Comment out the line which asks for CD rom

Type or paste into termimnal:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and you will be into text edit mode of the system file I mentioned above. Using arrow keys of your keyboard you have to navigate to the line which starts with `deb cdrom:[elementary OS ..` and put the `#` sign in front of it in order to became `#deb cdrom:[elementary OS..` or `# deb cdrom:[elementary OS..`. Press <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and then <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to quit the application.